# Using "it was" twice with "as if"

Tags: antecedents, dummy-it

This sentence is from [English Grammar Today](https://www.google.com/amp/s/dictionary.cambridge.org/amp/british-grammar/as-and-as-expressions/as-if-and-as-though) by the Cambridge Dictionary:

> The floods were rising and **it was** as if **it was** the end of the world.

My question is why should **it was** be there twice in that sentence?

I assume that the first *it was* refers back to the rising of the floods. Then what function does the second *it was* do?

Couldn't the sentence be acceptable if it were written as follows?

1. The floods were rising and it was as if the end of the world.

Or

2. The floods were rising as if the end of the world.

Comment: Both your alternatives are ungrammatical. _As if_ needs to be followed by a verb phrase, prepositional phrase, or adjectival phrase, not a noun phrase. Both instances of _it_ in the original are quite non-referential – they don’t refer back to anything. They both refer very vaguely to the general situation, as in “it’s raining” or “it’s a nice day”, and they’re both necessary if you want to keep the structure as two main clauses. Your second alternative would work if you left the second _it was_ in. (To some, including me, the second should be _it were_, but to others _it was_ is fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Both your alternatives are ungrammatical. *As if* needs to be followed by a verb phrase, prepositional phrase, or adjectival phrase, not a noun phrase. Both instances of *it* in the original are quite non-referential – they don’t refer back to anything. They both refer very vaguely to the general situation, as in “it’s raining” or “it’s a nice day”, and they’re both necessary if you want to keep the structure as two main clauses. Your second alternative would work if you left the second *it was* in. (To some, including me, the second should be *it were*, but to others, *it was* is fine.)

<sup><sup>Credit: [**Janus Bahs Jacquet**](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/508741/two-times-it-was-with-as-if#comment1232685_508741)</sup></sup>

Comment: Of course you could also just tack on “was upon us.” to the end of each.